Plotting energy level diagram in gnuplot
How can i plot an energy level diagram similar to the attached figure for the data file given below? ( In the energy section in the data file, successive rows correspond to different diffuseness values.)

orbitals = ['1s1/2', '1p3/2', '1p1/2', '1d5/2','1d3/2','2s1/2','1f7/2','1f5/2','2p3/2','2p1/2',

            '1g9/2','1g7/2','2d5/2','2d3/2','3s1/2','1h11/2','1h9/2','2f7/2','1i13/2']

neutron_energies = [

    [-1.227,-39.078,-38.630,-34.666,-33.512,-32.237,-29.683,-27.441,-25.945,-24.930,-24.211,-20.484,-19.296,-17.191,-17.014,-18.309,-12.704,-12.388,-12.017],

    [-1.261,-39.036,-38.583,-34.610,-33.445,-32.184,-29.614,-27.357,-25.890,-24.872,-24.130,-20.385,-19.246,-17.139,-16.977,-18.219,-12.597,-12.348,-11.919],

    [-1.295,-38.995,-38.536,-34.554,-33.379,-32.130,-29.544,-27.273,-25.835,-24.815,-24.050,-20.287,-19.196,-17.089,-16.941,-18.129,-12.491,-12.309,-11.821],

    [-1.329,-38.953,-38.489,-34.497,-33.312,-32.077,-29.475,-27.188,-25.780,-24.757,-23.969,-20.189,-19.146,-17.038,-16.905,-18.039,-12.385,-12.271,-11.724],

    [-1.362,-38.911,-38.441,-34.440,-33.244,-32.023,-29.405,-27.103,-25.725,-24.699,-23.889,-20.091,-19.096,-16.988,-16.869,-17.950,-12.279,-12.233,-11.628]

]



neutron_diffuseness = [0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56]


Any help is appreciated.
I don't know how to approach it wihtout completely restructuring the data file. Also, I don't know how to avoid the overlap of the labels.

Does the input data really look like that with empty lines within the brackets (especially within orbitals = [ ... ]) or is this a formatting issue on StackOverflow? I guess it can be made with gnuplot, but gnuplot is not made for efficient parsing, so it matters whether your have newlines within the data or not (unless you want to restructure your data with an external tool).

Problem solved? Question answered? Any feedback would be appreciated!

With your data format you have a few "challenges" for achieving the desired graph. The formatting in your question looks very special and a bit "random", e.g. especially the separation by empty lines of the orbital labels.
So, my assumption for the following is that the input data actually looks like this (if not, the script has to be adapted). The blocks of orbitals, neutron_energies and neutron_diffuseness are separated by two empty lines and the values are all in one line in brackets. With this, you can address the blocks easily via index (check help index).
Data: SO78498280.dat
orbitals = ['1s1/2','1p3/2','1p1/2','1d5/2','1d3/2','2s1/2','1f7/2','1f5/2','2p3/2','2p1/2','1g9/2','1g7/2','2d5/2','2d3/2','3s1/2','1h11/2','1h9/2','2f7/2','1i13/2']


neutron_energies = [
    [-1.227,-39.078,-38.630,-34.666,-33.512,-32.237,-29.683,-27.441,-25.945,-24.930,-24.211,-20.484,-19.296,-17.191,-17.014,-18.309,-12.704,-12.388,-12.017],
    [-1.261,-39.036,-38.583,-34.610,-33.445,-32.184,-29.614,-27.357,-25.890,-24.872,-24.130,-20.385,-19.246,-17.139,-16.977,-18.219,-12.597,-12.348,-11.919],
    [-1.295,-38.995,-38.536,-34.554,-33.379,-32.130,-29.544,-27.273,-25.835,-24.815,-24.050,-20.287,-19.196,-17.089,-16.941,-18.129,-12.491,-12.309,-11.821],
    [-1.329,-38.953,-38.489,-34.497,-33.312,-32.077,-29.475,-27.188,-25.780,-24.757,-23.969,-20.189,-19.146,-17.038,-16.905,-18.039,-12.385,-12.271,-11.724],
    [-1.362,-38.911,-38.441,-34.440,-33.244,-32.023,-29.405,-27.103,-25.725,-24.699,-23.889,-20.091,-19.096,-16.988,-16.869,-17.950,-12.279,-12.233,-11.628]
]


neutron_diffuseness = [0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56]

The challenges:

your data format is not advantageous for gnuplot, but you can convert it to a more suitable format. A better format would be something like this,

X   h1   h2   h3   h4   ...
x0  y01  y02  y03  y04  ...
x1  y11  y12  y13  y14  ...
x2  y21  y22  y23  y24  ...
x3  y31  y32  y33  y34  ...
...

where h1,h2,h3,... are the orbital labels, x0,x1,x2,... are the diffuseness values, and y01, y02, ... y11, y12, ... are the energy values. Of course, you could do this with an external tool, but usually, I prefer to do it all in gnuplot if somehow possible. However, since gnuplot want to be a plotting tool, it is not optimized for data restructuring. So, sometimes it might get a bit cumbersome.

the neutron energy values are not sorted by increasing or decreasing values, which will create some extra work to sort them first before trying to avoid overlap of the labels. Furthermore, if you want to color the lines differently, but identical color for the corresponding text labels, you need to remember the unsorted line number in a 3rd column in datablock $LabelsSorted.

The data is brought into arrays (check help arrays) using macros (check help macros) to be more flexible with indexing.
I guess there would be a few more things to explain, but before getting too verbose, check the following script and ask if you have more questions.
For further reading check: help strcol, help smooth, help strstrt, etc.
Script: (works with gnuplot>=5.2.7, May 2019)
### plotting energy diagram
reset session

FILE = "SO78498280.dat"

getArray(b,e) = (_s=strcol(1), _s[strstrt(_s,"[")+b : strstrt(_s,"]")+e])
set datafile separator "\n"

# get first lines of data into arrays
stats FILE index 0 u (orbitals=getArray(0,0)) nooutput
array O = @orbitals
stats FILE index 1 every ::1::1  u (energies=getArray(0,0)) nooutput
array E = @energies
stats FILE index 2 u (diffuseness=getArray(0,0)) nooutput
array D = @diffuseness

# restructure data
set table $Data
    plot FILE index 0 u ("X,".getArray(1,-1)) w table, \
           '' index 1 every ::1::5 u (sprintf("%g,%s",D[$0+1],getArray(1,-1))) w table
unset table
print $Data

# sort labels
set table $Labels
   plot E u (sprintf("%g %s",E[$0+1],O[$0+1])) w table
set table $Labels2
    set datafile separator whitespace
    plot $Labels u 1:0 smooth freq
set table $LabelsSorted
    plot $Labels2 u (sprintf("%g, %s, %g",E[$2+1], O[$2+1], $2)) w table
unset table
print $LabelsSorted

set datafile separator comma
set xlabel "diffuseness a_0 (fm)" enhanced
set xtics 0.01
set ylabel "E (MeV)
set key noautotitle
set autoscale fix
set offsets graph 0.2, graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1
dy = 1.0
y1 = NaN

plot for [i=2:20] $Data u 1:i w lp pt 7 ps 0.5 lc i-2, \
     $LabelsSorted u (D[1]):(y0=y1,y1=column(1), \
         abs(y1-y0)<dy ? dy0=dy0+dy-abs(y1-y0) : dy0=0, y1=y1+dy0):2:3 \
         w labels tc var right offset -1,0
### end of script

Result:
$Data:
X,'1s1/2','1p3/2','1p1/2','1d5/2','1d3/2','2s1/2','1f7/2','1f5/2','2p3/2','2p1/2','1g9/2','1g7/2','2d5/2','2d3/2','3s1/2','1h11/2','1h9/2','2f7/2','1i13/2'
0.52,-1.227,-39.078,-38.630,-34.666,-33.512,-32.237,-29.683,-27.441,-25.945,-24.930,-24.211,-20.484,-19.296,-17.191,-17.014,-18.309,-12.704,-12.388,-12.017
0.53,-1.261,-39.036,-38.583,-34.610,-33.445,-32.184,-29.614,-27.357,-25.890,-24.872,-24.130,-20.385,-19.246,-17.139,-16.977,-18.219,-12.597,-12.348,-11.919
0.54,-1.295,-38.995,-38.536,-34.554,-33.379,-32.130,-29.544,-27.273,-25.835,-24.815,-24.050,-20.287,-19.196,-17.089,-16.941,-18.129,-12.491,-12.309,-11.821
0.55,-1.329,-38.953,-38.489,-34.497,-33.312,-32.077,-29.475,-27.188,-25.780,-24.757,-23.969,-20.189,-19.146,-17.038,-16.905,-18.039,-12.385,-12.271,-11.724
0.56,-1.362,-38.911,-38.441,-34.440,-33.244,-32.023,-29.405,-27.103,-25.725,-24.699,-23.889,-20.091,-19.096,-16.988,-16.869,-17.950,-12.279,-12.233,-11.628

$LabelSorted:
-39.078, 1p3/2, 1
-38.63, 1p1/2, 2
-34.666, 1d5/2, 3
-33.512, 1d3/2, 4
-32.237, 2s1/2, 5
-29.683, 1f7/2, 6
-27.441, 1f5/2, 7
-25.945, 2p3/2, 8
-24.93, 2p1/2, 9
-24.211, 1g9/2, 10
-20.484, 1g7/2, 11
-19.296, 2d5/2, 12
-18.309, 1h11/2, 15
-17.191, 2d3/2, 13
-17.014, 3s1/2, 14
-12.704, 1h9/2, 16
-12.388, 2f7/2, 17
-12.017, 1i13/2, 18
-1.227, 1s1/2, 0

Output of terminal wxt: (set term wxt size 640,640)

